# Sorting ModelAdmin Columns in related Silverstripe tables

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

By default only the columnms of the current table are sortable in the modeladmin in Silverstripe. How do you make the related tables' column sortable as well in modeladmin>?

Comment: What do you mean by sortable? Do you mean the searchfields on the top (3.3) or left (3.1) of the ModelAdmin? Or do you mean the searchicon on the gridfield? Or do you use the SortableGridfield Module?

Comment: @Eagle the up and down arrow on the right side of the table/class name on top of modeladmin in Silverstripe 3.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting arrows at the right side of the gridfield columns come from the `GridFieldSortableHeader` component. Check the [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/forms/field_types/gridfield#gridfield) for more information.

Put this code in your 'Managed Model'

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $grid = $fields->dataFieldByName('YourRelation');
    $gridConfig = $grid->getConfig();
    $gridConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableHeader());

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: $grid = $fields->dataFieldByName('YourRelation'); 'YourRelation' is the in the $many_many array?

Comment: Yes. So if you have a `$many_many = ['Products' => 'Product'];` Then `YourRelation` would be `Products`